# How to provide frontend with token after server authentication (maybe by using axios)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, spotify

I am using the Spotify Web API to get my access token. It is working perfectly.

In my frontend application, I would like to use `axios` to get the access token.

How can I do that?

Because my `axios.get` method is not working.

Here I am getting the access token:

```
app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
```

your application requests refresh and access tokens after checking the state parameter

```
var code = req.query.code || null;
var state = req.query.state || null;
var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;
console.log('reqcookie', req.cookie)

if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
        querystring.stringify({
            error: 'state_mismatch'
        })
    );
} else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        form: {
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':'        
              +  
                     client_secret).toString('base64'))
        },
        json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
            console.log('accestoken ',access_token)
            console.log('body', body)

            var options = {
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token            
                },
                json: true
            };
```

Use the access token to access the Spotify Web API

```
request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('hi')
    console.log(body)  
});
```

...not important code

```
console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);
```

That's how I use `axios` in my frontend application to get the data and later the access token.

But it is currently not working

```
    axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/callback'
}).then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you edit your code to be more readable? Try making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes sure i can do that

Comment: What you usually do is:  log in person (can be done with axios) and then backend answers you with some token. you attach this token as for example header - almost like in your example - but one from server not your own. And then with each request backend tests if given token is approved or not.

Comment: Thanks, @danielragimov. This line: `request.post(...`, where is `request` defined? I can see `req` is defined but no `request`.

Comment: I important as a  dependencie  var request = require('request');

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/#error=state_mismatch due to access control checks.

Comment: Honestly my main problem, is just to remove the accesstoken from the url. I thought, if I can get the accesstoken in another way, I dont have to put the token to the browser

Comment: maybe you can help me with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432084/how-to-remove-accesstoken-from-the-url