# How to remove accesstoken from the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Right now I am getting my accesstoken from the url. I am using a GET request in the backend, which is passing the accesstoken to the URL.
They key problem is, after I logged in successfully the accesstoken stays in the URL. I don't know how to get rid of that.

```
function App() {
  // ( getSpotifyTokenFromUrl() ) That function is getting me the token from the url
  const params = getSpotifyTokenFromUrl();
  const token = params.access_token;

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        {token ? 
          <Route path="hompage">
            <Homepage spotify={spotify}/>
          </Route>
        : <Home />}
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
```

I also tried to do that in the `index.js` file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Route exact path="/hompage" component={Homepage} />
    </App>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is a small part of my backend code, which is passing the token to the browser. Maybe I have to redirect again, but how?

```js
res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#' +
  querystring.stringify({
    access_token: access_token,
    refresh_token: refresh_token
  }));
```

Comment: Can you change the route params using react-router?

Comment: what do you man exactly

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? I'm almost certain there's a way to change the route params without forcing a re-route. Check the docs. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: The key problem is I can not make a second res.redirect

Comment: The logging button is connected with the backend end.

Comment: You click on that and you get redirected to the url with the accesstoken it’s not possible to change the url after this process immediately

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but maybe the answer will help someone else.
I found your answer in this link: https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/ea3e43886534ff7c3efb6d389766e588
You can change App function like this:

```
function App() {
   const {location, history} = window;
   const {search} = location;
   const params = getSpotifyTokenFromUrl();
   var token = null;
   if (params !== null) {
     token = params.access_token;
     if (search && search.indexOf('access_token') !== -1 && history && 
         history.replaceState) {
         // remove access_token from url
         const cleanSearch = search.replace(/(\&|\?)access_token[^\&]*/g, 
         '').replace(/^&/, '?');
         // replace search params with clean params
         const cleanURL = location.toString().replace(search, cleanSearch)
         // use browser history API to clean the params
         history.replaceState({}, '', cleanURL)
         }
       }
   return (
     <Router>
      <div className="app">
       {token ? 
        <Route path="hompage">
          <Homepage spotify={spotify}/>
        </Route>
        : <Home />}
     </div>
    </Router>
    )     
    }
```